# NSMutableURLRequest sending null value on device but works in browser

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutableurlrequest

Before you read this please keep in mind that I am an Objective C programmer trying to help debug a server problem with a C# programmer who knows nothing about what I do.

I am sending a SOAP packet to a .net/c# side and the server receives nulls for the variables. When the url and variable string is put in the browser I get the proper response.

The post logs out to "?help=1& email=test@email.net & password=testpassword" but i keep getting "Result=Error&Details=Object reference not set to an instance of an object." back for my return string.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?help=1& email=? & password=%@",userEmail, userPassword];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:LOGIN_SERVICE]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"multipart/form-data" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

//Submit the Post:
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

/NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

//Extract Return:
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Can the server log the exact request that it receives from you?  (The null variables and bad object reference errors sound like they're happening during interpretation of whatever you send.)

Answer (score 2):

Your email variable within the format string wasnt being populated. And also, why do you have spaces in your post data? I imagine this is causing your issues. Because your data can contain spaces, you'll need to escape them.

Instead of:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?help=1& email=? & password=%@",userEmail, userPassword];
```

Try:

```
NSString* escapedUserEmail = [userEmail stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString* escapedUserPassword = [userPassword stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?help=1&email=%@&password=%@",escapedUserEmail, escapedUserPassword];
```

For more reading on the topic, refer to: http://deusty.blogspot.com/2006/11/sending-http-get-and-post-from-cocoa.html

Comment: I did as you suggested and I am still getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object.The part that confuses me is why does the device get this response but a browser does not.

Comment: How are you doing it in the browser?

Comment: That is how he is checking his services before I implement them.

Comment: As in, how is he checking his services? URL, server side console, ...? Also, please post an exact copy of the NSString 'post' variable contents.

Comment: He is checking them through URL and the post variable is ?help=1&email=test@email.com&password=password

Comment: That @ sign needs escaping (it needs to change to %40), did you escape the email address like in the answer?

Comment: Wait! If he's doing it via URL, then that's not POST, that's GET.